# Can someone explain this colon # syntax

Tags: c++, c

I came across a syntax I've never seen before.

```
typedef struct SomeStruct
{
    unsigned char ip_version :4;
    unsigned char ip_tos;
    unsigned char ip_frag_offset :5;
    unsigned char ip_more_fragment :1;
    unsigned char ip_dont_fragment :1;
    unsigned char ip_reserved_zero :1;
    unsigned char ip_frag_offset1;
    unsigned char ip_ttl;
} SomeHeader;
```

What is the `colon #;` for? Is that the same as using the assignment operator? Why use the colon and is there advantages or a reason this is allowed?

Comment: Try googling "bit-fields"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are bit fields:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yszfawxh(v=vs.80).aspx
- http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html

It should be noted you could have found this by searching Google for "c struct syntax".  For me, the first result was wikipedia, which has a [bit field section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Bit_fields)